# how to pass multiple generic arguments

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

i was wondering if there's a way to build a class which can accept multiple generic arguments 
that aren't known at compile time

```
   class Something<T,V,U>
```

this example shows a class which would expect to receive 3 generic arguments at run time.
i'm looking for a way to specify a class which would except multiple arguments of a varied amount

something along the line of

```
    class Something<T[]>
```

which i could later expose using reflection

```
  Type [] types = GetType().GetGenericArguments();
```

Comment: Variadic generic parameters? I don't think so.

Comment: The main purpose of using Generics is to assure type safety at compile time. If you don't know the generic parameters involved until run time then you are not trying to use generics correctly.

Comment: i never use them like i suggested i'm just building some kind a layered indexing component with its layer holds a sorted dictionary with a key of a different generic type , i thought if something like
a varied amount a arguments existed it would save me the hardship of a messy workaround . 

thanks for disregarding that notion.

Comment: Are you trying to create a single class that contains all the layers, or are you going for something more like the composite pattern?

Comment: sorry mate i don't know what a composite pattern is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make some class - a kind of

```
public static class TypeHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypeCombination(this Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(T<,>))
            return type.GetGenericArguments().SelectMany(GetTypeCombination);

        return new Type[] { type };
    }
}

public class T<T1, T2>
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypeCombination()
    {
        return typeof(T1).GetTypeCombination()
            .Concat(typeof(T2).GetTypeCombination());
    }
}
```

and to use that as

```
var list = T<int, T<string, int[]>>.GetTypeCombination().ToList();
```

to get (pass) dynamic list of types - not sure it's the best way

Comment: you can't pass variable count of generic parameters, but you can pass a type which combines several (a pair) of them (each element of this pair can be also a combinator of 2)

Comment: thanks i need to try that out..
it just seems above my league for now.

Answer (score 10):

You can't specify an *unknown* number of generics.  The closest you can get is to define all possible variations, or at least as many as you're willing to handle. I recommend using an abstract base class too. For example:

```
public abstract class Something { }
public class Something<T1> : Something { }
public class Something<T1, T2> : Something { }
public class Something<T1, T2, T3> : Something { }
public class Something<T1, T2, T3, T4> : Something { }
public class Something<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5> : Something { }
...
```

The abstract class is useful for when you need to reference the type but don't know the number of generic arguments.

Depending on your evil intentions you may end up writing a lot of redundant code using this solution in which case you should reconsider your use of generics.

Comment: thanks i'm working on i thought about a work around
i get my T using Reflection 
And Then inside Something<T> i Create another Something<U> using reflection inside Something  and that could be done a number of times down 
ill post my answer later if i get something done .